# Nesting views with a node reference field

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am creating a Drupal site that is used as a task manager; each task node has the ability to reference another task node as a parent.
In the task list view, I would like to nest the same or similar view within each row, displaying that tasks children.

I've done something similar before by theming; however, I'm wondering if is there a standard, or emerging way of accomplishing this within the Views interface with a third-party module.

Comment: Ideally I envision a field, similar to the Global: View Area, which could accept contextual filters as tokens, not that such a thing necessarily exists, but it would be cool I think :)

Comment: i had installed node reference field. module but cant see this as widget in my cck manage field menu ..please help to find it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it with [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield).

> View arguments are supplied through tokens.

So, what you should do:

1. Add new type of your view (new Block, for example) and add contextual filter by node reference field.
   You can modify display format etc.
2. Create for your tasks new field "View Reference" and set your new display type of view. Check «Always use default value».
3. Set `[node:nid]` in Arguments input.

Tested on D7.

Comment: I have a similar question, could you read it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412802/using-token-to-pass-id-in-url-fron-node-to-view-using-viewfield